# Start animation when node is near

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have 2 nodes with textures (SKSpriteNode) and I'm trying to create some animation when node is near with another node with y-axis (with range 100 - 0) and animation start at this moment.
I'm trying to do something like Cut The Rope, when candy is near Om-Nom and he opening his mouth to catch the candy.
Help me with code please(
Sorry for my english

Comment: I don't know if this is project is linked to your old question. Have you take a look to my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this kind of calculation with few line of code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var sprite1 : SKSpriteNode!
    var sprite2 : SKSpriteNode!
    var range : CGFloat = 0.0
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.range = randomCGFloat(0.0, max: 100.0)
        sprite1 = SKSpriteNode.init(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(40,40))
        sprite2 = SKSpriteNode.init(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(40,40))
        addChild(sprite1)
        addChild(sprite2)
        // Try to generate 10 positions and check relative distance
        print("The range to check is :\(range)")
        for i in 0...9 {
            print("\(i)) time:")
            let isNear = checkDistanceBtwSprites()
            if isNear {
                // do whatever you want with your sprites
            }
        }
    }
    func checkDistanceBtwSprites()->Bool{
        sprite1.position = getRandomPosition(40, maxX: 40, minY: 0, maxY: 320)
        sprite2.position = getRandomPosition(40, maxX: 40, minY: 0, maxY: 320)
        let distance = getDistance((sprite1.position), p2: (sprite2.position))
        print("distance for sprite1 and sprite2 is : \(distance)")
        if distance <= self.range {
            print("# -> success: sprite1 is near sprite2")
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    func getRandomPosition(minX: CGFloat, maxX: CGFloat, minY:CGFloat, maxY:CGFloat)->CGPoint {
        return CGPointMake(randomCGFloat(minX, max: maxX),randomCGFloat(minY, max: maxY))
    }
    func randomCGFloat(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat)->CGFloat {
        return (CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX)) * (max - min) + min
    }
    func getDistance(p1:CGPoint,p2:CGPoint)->CGFloat {
        let xDist = (p2.x - p1.x)
        let yDist = (p2.y - p1.y)
        return CGFloat(sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist)))
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]